# Aerospike Nodejs Client Query Processing

Tags: python, node.js, coffeescript, aerospike

Current examples shown are with stream: http://www.aerospike.com/docs/client/nodejs/usage/query/aggregate.html

Is there a simpler/way where we can just do:

```
  options = filters: [ filter.equal('from_user', user_id) or filter.equal('to_user', user_id) ]
  q = client.query('polls', 'chat', options)
  allRecordsListJson= q.execute()
```

This can be done in python and other clients.

Comment: One simple way is to call the python snippet from nodejs but want to avoid doing it.

Answer (score 2):

Aerospike does not yet support queries with mutliple where clauses with AND/OR conjunctions. So for now, you have to use only one cause and do the filtration at the client level or use stream aggregation and write LUA code to do the filtration and pass the parameters.